# Keep hover() working with right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div on my page that calls a function when the mouse hovers over it. The problem is that I still need have hover() activated when someone right clicks on the div and opens the context menu.

So, is there a solution to this?

Comment: i guess that the right click happens after the mouse get inside the div. So they are separated events, can you post your code ?

Comment: [Where is your code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could try :focus instead of :hover.